# How to read a file in Heroku environment/on Heroku's machine? Java

Tags: java, heroku, readfile

I am able to read file locally. Structure:

```
somePackage
    -- A.class
    -- someFile.properties
```

Code that works locally, looks like this:

```
InputStream stream = A.class.getResourceAsStream("someFile.properties");
-- then I pass the stream and continue my work
```

or like this:

```
String filePath = A.class.getResource("someFile.properties").getPath();
-- then I pass the path, open the file and continue my work
```

When deployed to Heroku I get null pointer or file not found exceptions.

So why none of these work on Heroku's ***container***?

**Note:** My "A" class is utility like class so I never instantiate "A" objects.

---

**SOLVED:** I moved the someFile.properties to src/main/resources (someFile.properties is in WEB-INF/classes when packed to .war) and used this code to get the path, **note** the leading "/"

```
String path = "/" + A.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()  + "someFile.properties";
```

I think there is a better way to get directory of the "classes" but this way fits my needs at the moment.

Comment: Are you testing locally by running `heroku local`? This would ensure that the classpath is set up the same way as on Heroku. This problem is most likely due to a difference in classpaths (is someFile.properties inside a JAR?)

Comment: Nope - using either Maven or Tomcat in Eclipse, and the file is not in a .jar. I think I should get a habbit of testing apps with `heroku local`, shouldn't I? Anyway you are my savior again:) After testing app with `heroku local` I now see that someFile.properties is not even in WEB-INF\classes where my other .properties files are (those other .properties files are under src/main/resources) . I have made a copy of someFile.properties and moved it to src/main/resources so it should be under WEB-INF/classes...

Comment: Maybe build/refresh problems(?). At least I can now continue work on this issue, thank you! Will let you know how I solved it.

Comment: After runing `mvn clean install` my app now finds the file when I run `heroku local`.  Question is how I do make it to behave same way on Heroku's machine... Note: I am certain the file is commited to the branch I deploy my app from.

Comment: `mvn clean install` will run on Heroku, so the file should be in the same place. You can confirm with `heroku run bash` and then use `ls` and `cd` to look for the file. Then open a ticket at https://help.heroku.com so a support engineer can inspect the filesystem.

Comment: So for some reason I don't know .properties file is not in somePackage when deployed to Heroku. However when I put it under resources folder it is there when deployed but then I get http://prntscr.com/dskwnd (look at path printed) . When looking for the file according to that address http://prntscr.com/dskx8a . When extracted I can see that .war faile contains someFile.properties under WEB-INF/classes